# How to import DB tables from mysqlhotcopy?

Tags: mysql

I used mysqlhotcopy to dump a database full of tables.  I know have various .frm, .MYD, and .MYI files that I need to import into a different instance of MySQL.  Do I just copy these files into a specific folder on the 2nd system, or do I have to run mysqlhotcopy with another command line option to perform the import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the binary data files for your tables - if you have a .frm, .MYD and .MYI for each, you can copy those into your database folder (typically `/var/lib/mysql/<schema-name>/`). Stop your database first though!

If you make mysqlhotcopy run a bit faster with the [--noindices](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlhotcopy.html#option_mysqlhotcopy_noindices) option, then after copying the files you'll need to recreate the indices from the data files - inside the database directory, run `myisamchk -rq`

Comment: I figured that's all it was, but I couldn't find documentation that spelled it out, and I also wasn't sure what path I needed.  Thanks for the info! :)